# Can we exchange the order of matrix products in trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can we do this? Why?

$tr(ABC) = tr(BCA) = tr(ACB) = \cdots$

Comment: Yes. We have $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$, so $tr(ABC) = tr(BCA)$.

Comment: @GAVD What about $tr(ACB)$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$C=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $\operatorname{tr} (ABC) = 0,
\operatorname{tr} (ACB) = -1$.

If they are symmetric, however, it is true (for three matrices).